# UIEdgeInset issue positioning text/image

Tags: iphone, image, uibutton, title

I try to make an `UIButton` with image upper the text, so I use this code:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 140, 140);
[btn setTitle:self.objMateria.titoloMateria forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pala.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 20, 0);
btn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(120, 0, 0, 0);
```

the problem is that with this code I don't see the text, that seems to be covered by the image, where is the mistake?

here the image:
[image]

Comment: Post your image also so that i can test it here. Or tell what is the size of the image.

Comment: I post the image on the question, thank you

Comment: so where are you setting your text.. if it is label then what is it frame...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
btn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 0, 0, 0);
btn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(120, -120, 0, 0);
```

Adjust the value of `-120` i.e. *left* to horizontally fit your title

Comment: whit this code the button work perfectly, can I ask you how the UIEdgeInsetsMake work? I try to read also Apple doc but I don't understand how it work :(

Comment: I just put a button of 140x140 on xib and set it's image to yours the changed the UIEdgeInsets for both image and text and then I found the final/correct. It's easier to work with xib than code :)

Comment: but the logic? why you need to set -120 on left? I read that UIEdgeInsetsMake creates an edge, bou for what I want I need to create a margin at the bottom of image and at the top of title, why alse on the left?

Comment: I don't know much but that's what I know and how I got

Answer (score 1):

Can you please modify your code as follows?

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 140, 140);
[btn setTitle:@"pala" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pala.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 0, 0, 0);
UIImage *imageTemp = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pala.png"];
btn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(imageTemp.size.height, -imageTemp.size.width, 0, 0);
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Comment: And also, you can modify imageEdgeInsets and titleEdgeInsets by creating a temporary UIButton in interface builder and modifying it.

Comment: thank you, I solve perfectly with the code upper your answer.

Comment: Excuse me, now I understand your comment! only one thing, with upper answer all work but with imageTemp.size.height, -imageTemp.size.width not work, why?

Comment: Create a UIButton in interface builder and modify it so that it works fine.