# How to Display Image over Button? -Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am creating a ***UIButton*** programmatically and set the title, image as the below code. The problem is whenever i click on the button the image gets **highlighted** but the title of the button does not. So, i want to create the animation effect of both or none. As well as should i give constraints or what so that image gets right of the text **"SORT"**?

[image]

Comment: If you want animation for both and have placements right, you might choose to create custom component using UIView, and use touches with selection animations in it. For placement of image in button you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915898/uiedgeinset-issue-positioning-text-image

Comment: Use state Attribute of UIButton from Attributes inspector

Comment: @iphonic thanks it worked to give the insets. but my problem was not solved.. I tried changing the UIbutton type to System button. It solved my problem but the color was changed to the default color blue of sytem type

Comment: @anishparajuli you can always change the textcolor and fonts like this `[button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[button titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0]];`

Comment: yah..i changed the title color as   btnSort.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal). But unfortunately there is the image and its color became  blue after i made the button to type system and i cant change the color of image to white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I nailed it. I changed the button type to System button and the color changed to blue. However i managed to change the Blue color to white by setting the tint color to white which apple uses by default to set the color to its controls(i guess). So the system button color to blue was due to the reason the tintcolor was assigned as blue

```
let btnSort   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
btnSort.frame =  CGRectMake(2, 74, 140, 26)
btnSort.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
btnSort.setImage(UIImage(named:"drop_arrow"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btnSort.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6,left: 100,bottom: 6,right: 14)
btnSort.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: -30,bottom: 0,right: 34)
btnSort.setTitle("SORT", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btnSort.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
btnSort.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
btnSort.addTarget(self, action: Selector("showSortTbl"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(btnSort)
```

Comment: I am not getting the title using this method, image is appearing however the title is not coming. Will you look into it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for sample, you can try it. I have created one button programatically and assign image with the help of `EdgeInsets` property.

```
       let btnDemo : UIButton  = UIButton() 
        btnDemo.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 75, width: 65, height: 18)
        btnDemo.setImage(UIImage(named:"drop_arrow_sample"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btnDemo.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6,left: 100,bottom: 6,right: 14)
        btnDemo.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: -30,bottom: 0,right: 34)
        btnDemo.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 13)
        btnDemo.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        btnDemo.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        btnDemo.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 189/255, green: 176/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)                      
        btnDemo.tag = index
        btnDemo.addTarget(self, action: "SortTable:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```