# add rightview in UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton, uiimage

I am trying to display some text and an image over a button. I am using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225927/how-to-display-image-over-button-swift)

```
    let btnSort   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
    btnSort.frame =  CGRectMake(2, 74, 140, 26)
    btnSort.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    btnSort.setImage(UIImage(named:"immgg"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btnSort.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6,left: 100,bottom: 6,right: 14)
    btnSort.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: -30,bottom: 0,right: 34)
    btnSort.setTitle("SORT", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btnSort.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    btnSort.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    btnSort.addTarget(self, action: Selector("showSortTbl"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(btnSort)
```

I can see the image at the right place, however the text is not appearing. I think `titleEdgeInsets` is not working.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

the code I tried I got the output what the problem U faced.

`btnSort.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()` --> set the background color and check

```
 let btnSort   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton! //this is Swift2.0 in this place use your code
    btnSort.frame =  CGRectMake(2, 74, 140, 40)
    btnSort.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    btnSort.setImage(UIImage(named:"youtube16x16.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btnSort.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6,left: 100,bottom: 6,right: 14)
    btnSort.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: -30,bottom: 0,right: 34)
    btnSort.setTitle("SORT", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btnSort.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    btnSort.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() --> set the background color and check 
    btnSort.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    btnSort.addTarget(self, action: Selector("showSortTbl"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(btnSort)
```

**Swift3**

```
 let btnSort   = UIButton(type: .system)
    btnSort.frame =  CGRect(x: 2, y: 74, width: 140, height: 40)
    btnSort.tintColor = UIColor.white
    btnSort.setImage(UIImage(named:"youtube16x16.png"), for: .normal)
    btnSort.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6,left: 100,bottom: 6,right: 14)
    btnSort.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: -30,bottom: 0,right: 34)
    btnSort.setTitle("SORT", for: .normal)
    btnSort.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    btnSort.backgroundColor = UIColor.red //--> set the background color and check
    btnSort.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    btnSort.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.showSortTbl), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(btnSort)
```

and handle the action as

```
  func showSortTbl() {
    // do your stuff here

}
```

output

[image]

Comment: Seriously, I don't know what the issue is however I am still not getting it. I checked with redcolor. Does it have issue cause I am using swift 1.2?

Comment: @Saty -- I just add the backgroundcolor of your button and checked I showed the answer also , r u tried the updated answer

Comment: When I remove the image, I see the text , I am using 
UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton as I am using swift 1.2. I think this is causing the issue

Comment: no no bro not like that , ok try once in this place  UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) use  UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) and   btnSort.frame =  CGRectMake(2, 74, 140, 40) try once

Comment: I am sorry bro!!! you are absolutely right!!! its because I am using a image of size 200X200. Thats why not working!!!!!

Comment: You are not zero of Objective C..You are a Hero

Comment: @Saty - not like bro, the small issue confused ourself in more times , if we can checked in step by step we identify the easily

Answer (score 4):

**Subclass `UIButton`**

**Override the `layoutSubviews()` function**

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        guard imageView != nil else {
         return
        }

        imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: (bounds.width - 25), bottom: 5, right: 5)
        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: imageView!.frame.width)

     }
}
```

- Add a button to Storyboard
- Add custom class to the button
- Change button type to System
- Set Title and image to the button

Answer (score 0):

Set only background color and display your text :

```
let btnSort = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton // Shift 2.0

btnSort.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

**OR**

```
btnSort.setTitleColor(UIColor.greenColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code.

Hope it will work for you.

```
let teamImage: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 75, width: 100, height: 50))
let imageTest = UIImage(named: "immgg")

teamImage.setTitle("HypnotoadTitle", forState: .Normal)
teamImage.setBackgroundImage(imageTest, forState: .Normal)
self.view.addSubview(teamImage)
```