# Display Image and Title Simultaneously on UIButton - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

How can I display a title and image simultaneously on a UIbutton? I tried to follow [Display image and text in Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033737/display-image-and-text-in-button) which uses swift 2 but the same process only displays the image in swift 3, with the title hidden. The image source file is 35x35 pixels. My code:

```
  let folderButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100 , y: 200, width: 200, height: 41))
  folderButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
  folderButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
  folderButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 162,bottom: 3,right: 3)
  folderButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 41)
  folderButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"FolderIcon35"), for: UIControlState.normal)
  folderButton.setTitle("Test", for: UIControlState.selected)
  folderButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
  view.addSubview(folderButton)
```

[current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFUCp.png)

Need a programatic solution as I am not using storyboard. Thanks!

Comment: please confirm your image up to only folder that is showing, or image upto showing border of black color ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should set the title for **UIControlState.normal**

```
folderButton.setTitle("Test", for:.normal)
```

Comment: Thanks! was my bad for missing the UIControlState.selected typo

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `folderButton.setTitle("yourTitle", for: UIControlState. normal)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are setting your title for `UIButton` selected mode only. SO when you select the button the title should display with your current code. For showing title in normal mode you should change the title set state to `.normal`.

`folderButton.setTitle("Test", for: UIControlState.normal)`

Answer (score 0):

For UIButton in iOS, we can change the appearance of button depending upon the state, namely Normal and Selected. 
Here, you are setting the title of button when button is pressed so you need to add additional line to your code by setting the state to normal.

folderButton.setTitle("Test", for: UIControlState.selected)
folderButton.setTitle("Test", for: UIControlState.normal)

For more reference on UIButton in ios, Visit: [UIButton](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton)