# Swift 3 - Most appropriate way to create a button with a scalable image above text

Tags: swift, button

In Android I was able to accomplish this custom button by creating a `LinearLayout` with 2 children-an `ImageView` and a `TextView`, and just controlling the layout properties (and adding onClick, etc. to recreate button functionality). Using weights, I was able to have the image scale to fill the button while allowing the appropriate proportions for the text.

For Example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:onClick="onClickFunction"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/icon_test" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_button_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button Text"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Produces:

[image: Button example]

---

What is the most appropriate way to do this in Swift 3? I've read about using insets to control the positioning (even setting negative "Left" insets on the image to position it above the text), but the image dimensions would have to be managed manually. I've also been made aware that setting the image as the background would have it scale, but I don't want to have the text overlap the image. My thought process is that there could be a "workaround" of sorts similar to my example above for Android, but I doubt the solution will be similar.

Furthermore, I'm pretty dependent on the IB (my app is not very complex so it's easily managed), so I'm using this for my button so far:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RoundButton: UIButton {

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0{
    didSet{
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0{
    didSet{
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear{
    didSet{
        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
    }
}
}
```

If it's not asking too much I'd like to be able to build off of this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example how you can achieve that:

```
let btnSort   = UIButton(type: .system)
    btnSort.frame =  CGRect(x: 2, y: 74, width: 140, height: 140)
    btnSort.tintColor = UIColor.white
    btnSort.setImage(UIImage(named:"lamp"), for: .normal)
    btnSort.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6,left: 20,bottom: 30,right: 20)
    btnSort.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100,left: -250,bottom: 0,right: 0)
    btnSort.setTitle("BUTTON TEXT", for: .normal)
    btnSort.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    btnSort.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    btnSort.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    self.view.addSubview(btnSort)
```

And result will be:

[image]

And here is the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033737/display-image-and-text-in-button) post. I have changed `EdgeInsets` as per your requirement.

Comment: Where do I put this code so I can see the result in the interface builder? In the question I show that I have my own button class. Can I incorporate this into that, and if so, how?